# tetrahedron height

Tags: triangles

I've got the next figure:
[image]

Now I would like to calculate the height, so from D to the plane ABC. 
First, I've tried with a coordinate system, but it's to difficult to take these distances into account.
Then I remarked that all the faces (the triangulars) are similar. But I don't see if I can use that to calculate the height.

Can someone give me an idea about how to start?

Silke

Answer (score 0):

Put A at (0,0,0}, and B at (0,15,0).  Calculate C at (x,y,0).  Then solve the intersection of the three sphere equations.